# Need help turning an associative array into nested JSON using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I've been struggling with this for the past week and it's driving me crazy so if anyone could help me out I'd be forever grateful.

After querying my database I iterate through the data with:

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {...
```

This is how the rows are constructed:

**Example row 1:**

```
(
"countryId" => "2",
"countryDescription" => "Canada",
"cityId" => "3",
"cityDescription" => "Montreal",
"restaurantFranchiseId" => "2",
"restaurantFranchiseDescription" => "Kentucky Fried Chicken"
)
```

**Example row 2:**

```
(
"countryId" => "2",
"countryDescription" => "Canada",
"cityId" => "3",
"cityDescription" => "Montreal",
"restaurantFranchiseId" => "3",
"restaurantFranchiseDescription" => "Taco Bell"
)
```

Notice that only the restaurant franchise differs in the two rows above. The country and the city are the same in both rows.

I want to turn the rows in to a nested JSON-file like the one below. As you can see below, each country is a unique object. Each city is an unique object and a child element of it's corresponding country object. The restaurant franchises however aren't unique, since they aren't tied to a specific country or city.

How can create the JSON-file below from my data, which is structured as described above?

**THANKS!!!**

```
{
"Countries": [{
    "countryId": "1",
    "countryDescription": "USA",
    "cities": [{
        "cityId": "1",
        "cityDescription": "Houston",
        "restaurantFranchises": [{
            "restaurantFranchiseId": "1",
            "restaurantFranchiseDescription": "Mc Donald's"
        }, {
            "restaurantFranchiseId": "2",
            "restaurantFranchiseDescription": "Kentucky Fried Chicken"
        }, {
            "restaurantFranchiseId": "4",
            "restaurantFranchiseDescription": "Pizza Hut"
        }]
    }, {
        "cityId": "2",
        "cityDescription": "New york",
        "restaurantFranchises": [{
            "restaurantFranchiseId": "1",
            "restaurantFranchiseDescription": "Mc Donald's"
        }, {
            "restaurantFranchiseId": "4",
            "restaurantFranchiseDescription": "Pizza Hut"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "countryId": "2",
    "countryDescription": "Canada",
    "cities": [{
        "cityId": "3",
        "cityDescription": "Montreal",
        "restaurantFranchises": [{
            "restaurantFranchiseId": "1",
            "restaurantFranchiseDescription": "Mc Donald's"
        }, {
            "restaurantFranchiseId": "3",
            "restaurantFranchiseDescription": "Taco Bell"
        }, {
            "restaurantFranchiseId": "4",
            "restaurantFranchiseDescription": "Pizza Hut"
        }]
    }, {
        "cityId": "4",
        "cityDescription": "Ottawa",
        "restaurantFranchises": [{
            "restaurantFranchiseId": "2",
            "restaurantFranchiseDescription": "Kentucky Fried Chicken"
        }, {
            "restaurantFranchiseId": "3",
            "restaurantFranchiseDescription": "Taco Bell"
        }, {
            "restaurantFranchiseId": "4",
            "restaurantFranchiseDescription": "Pizza Hut"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

}

Comment: Could you please give me an array of your raw data : [{row},...,{row}] to test my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this code:

```
$result = [];
$lastCity = [ "cityId" => null ];
$lastCountry = [ "countryId" => null ];
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($row["countryId"] !== $lastCountry["countryId"]) {
        // Country is not the same as in previous row, so create
        // a new entry for it in the first level of the result array. 
        // The city and franchises data will be inserted further down.
        $result[] = [
            "countryId" => $row["countryId"],
            "countryDescription" => $row["countryDescription"],
            "cities" => []
        ];
        // Get a reference (`&`) to the new country entry added to `$result`.
        // Whatever is later changed in `$lastCountry` will change inside the
        // `$result` data structure.
        $lastCountry = &$result[count($result)-1];
    }
    if ($row["cityId"] !== $lastCity["cityId"]) {
        // City is not the same as in previous row, so create
        // a new entry for it in the second level of `$result`.
        // We use the `$lastCountry` "shortcut" to manipulate `$result`.
        $lastCountry["cities"][] = [
            "cityId" => $row["cityId"],
            "cityDescription" => $row["cityDescription"],
            "restaurantFranchises" => []
        ];
        // Get a reference (`&`) to the new city entry added to `$result`.
        // Whatever is later changed in `$lastCity` will change inside the
        // `$result` data structure (and `$lastCountry`).
        $lastCity = &$lastCountry["cities"][count($lastCountry["cities"])-1];
    }
    // Create a new entry for the franchise in the third level of `$result`.
    // We use the `$lastCity` "shortcut" to manipulate `$result`.
    $lastCity["restaurantFranchises"][] = [
        "restaurantFranchiseId" => $row["restaurantFranchiseId"],
        "restaurantFranchiseDescription" => $row["restaurantFranchiseDescription"],
    ];
}
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/599816).

#### About the helper variables

The two variables `$lastCity` and `$lastCountry` are references to locations in the `$result` data structure (except at the start of the loop, when they are dummy values). To get such references inside the `$result` array, the [`&` operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php) is used. It could be done without these two variables, but it would make the assignment statements quite long, as you would need to reference each time the last element in the `$result` array, get from that element the last element in its `cities` array, ...etc.

#### Assumptions

This algorithm needs your query result set to be ordered by country and city, i.e. a city should not first be "New York", then "Los Angeles" and then "New York" again.

Also, it is assumed that **cityId** values are unique. For example, a city in the US should not have the same **cityId** as a city in Canada. If this is the case, then the above code should be slightly adapted.

Comment: I just applied your code to my real data and it works perfect! I can not thank you enough @trincot! I sincerely appreciate the fact that you took your time to help me out with this.

Comment: I'm going to study your code and try to understand what it's doing. There are some things in there which are totally new to me. I also have to make sure that my sql sorts the data by country and city.

Comment: I added some comments in the code, which might help to understand it. I also added a link to the PHP docs concerning the [`&` operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php).